# Undefined Constructor in android

Tags: java, android, constructor, fragment, undefined

I'm making an app that deals with a fragment and I keep getting an undefined error for a constructor.

`

```
public class ClientFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final ClientFragment This = null;
    final ClientFragment context = This;
    private static String TAG = "This thing here";
    private static final String DIALOG_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final int REQUEST_PHOTO = 1;
    static final String EXTRA_MEM_ID = "com.example.project2.memID";

    private Scrap mScraps;
    Uri imageFileUri;



    public static ClientFragment newInstance(UUID memID) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_MEM_ID, memID);
        ClientFragment fragment = new ClientFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this snags the UUID sent from MainActivity and tosses it to BookMarks
        UUID memId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_MEM_ID);
        mScraps = BookMarks.get(getActivity()).getScraps(memId);
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scraps, parent, false);





    final ListView mListView= (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ScrapAdapter adapter = new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter); //setListAdapter sets the adapter to a specific listview

return v;
}


    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST = 0;


    private class ScrapAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Scrap> {
        public ScrapAdapter(ArrayList<Scrap> scraps) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, scraps);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_memory, null);
            }
            // Configure the view 
            Scrap c = getItem(position);
            //shows title
            TextView titleTextView =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
            //shows date memory was made
            TextView dateTextView =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dateTextView);
            dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
            return convertView;
        }
    }}`
```

The error is coming from `ScrapAdapter adapter = new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);` specifically the `new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);`

The error I receive is "The constructor ClientFragment.ScrapAdapter(Scrap) is undefined"

Comment: You need to pass the ArrayList to Adapter constructor but you are passing single Scrap object

Answer (score 0):

your constructor accepts an `ArrayList<Scrap>` as argument

```
public ScrapAdapter(ArrayList<Scrap> scraps)
```

but you are passing an `Scrap` object to it instead

```
ScrapAdapter adapter = new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass ArrayList of Scrap to ScrapAdapter :

```
ArrayList<Scrap> mScraps;
ScrapAdapter adapter = new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);
```

Or change ScrapAdapter constructor parameter ArrayList to  Scrap :

```
public ScrapAdapter(Scrap scraps) {
   super(getActivity(), 0, scraps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor need an `ArrayList` :

```
public ScrapAdapter(ArrayList<Scrap> scraps)
```

But you are passing an `Object`, not the `ArrayList` of `Object` :

```
private Scrap mScraps;
ScrapAdapter adapter = new ScrapAdapter(mScraps);
```

Maybe what you need to do is creating an `ArrayList` of `Scrap` and pass it. Or maybe, you want to change your constructor's parameter to receive a `Scrap` instead of  `ArrayList`.